# Add triangle at bottom of material design tab mat-ink-bar

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I want to change the style of the `mat-ink-bar` for [Angular material tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples).

I wanted to archieve a design like this: [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9AbYc/1/)

The problem is that the `mat-ink-bar` already `absolute` positioned and i cannot display my `::after` element. Is there a way how i can archieve this ?

Here is what i tried on stackblitz: [Mat tab on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-ink)

my style are located inside the `style.css`. The triangle at the bottom is hidden if you use the dev tool. I could not show it using `z-index`.. Any help would be appreciated.

here the code:

**css**

```
.c-tab .mat-ink-bar {
  height: 5px;
}

.c-tab .mat-ink-bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #3f51b5;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-tab-group class="c-tab">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

should look like this: 
[image]

Comment: Could you please add relevant code in this post and not external links.
`position: absolute` does not prevent you from using `::after`

Comment: @CodeSpirit i edited the post with the relevant html and css code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-ink-ab29wn?file=styles.css

Comment: please check its that work for you

Comment: @harkeshkumar. It should look like describe in my edited post

Comment: for that you have you normal tab not material tabs

Comment: First of all, you know that you have in your html clases which your are not using in your css right? 

And second :) You are not using position relative. I guess that for the moment your arrow is on the top of your window. :)

Comment: @Rakowu do you have a forked example or a solution ?

Comment: i leave a jsfiddle above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update following css will resolve your issue.

```
.mat-tab-label {
  position: relative;
}
.mat-tab-header,
.mat-tab-label-container,
.mat-ripple {
  overflow: inherit !important;
}
.mat-ink-bar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 20px #673ab7;
  border-left: solid 20px transparent;
  border-right: solid 20px transparent;
}
```

Checkout [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-ink-ab8jvf?file=styles.css)

Comment: Thank for your response..I edited only for mat-tab-label active, but it should move at the same time for better user experience..any idea ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-ink-afc4db?file=styles.css

Comment: Done.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-ink-ab8jvf?file=styles.css

Comment: Thanks..Better than nothing..can you please update your answer for other users ?

Comment: yeah..But you need to update your answer first with the correct code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `display:block` for your `::after` element. So block properties dont apply.
Additionally you are stretching the width of the `::after` to match its parent by using `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`.

Position either to top left or bottom right, not both`

Comment: there is no need for display block becouse he is using border :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.c-tab .mat-ink-bar {
  position:relative
}
```

Try just this ^^...

Theoretically that is all you need:
*updatet*
https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/e42wng0m/4/

Comment: There is even no need for height 5px. Just use border-top 5px (container not after :))