# How do you remove the Angular Material mat-ink-bar?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am having trouble getting the ink bar to be hidden.  I have tried a multitude of different things, but with no success.  Here is the CSS I currently have, which does change the color of the ink-bar.  I wish to disable and hide it completely to remove the border shadow.

```
/* active tab ink bar */
::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color,$orange) !important;
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
  transition: none !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  width: 0px !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's not the **mat-tab-nav-bar** :

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header, .mat-tab-nav-bar {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

You can check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554495/add-triangle-at-bottom-of-material-design-tab-mat-ink-bar).

Comment: You were correct, adding the above code in my CSS worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in changing the active tab style i fixed it using the below style.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    height: 3rem !important;
    min-width: 8rem !important;
}

/* Styles for the active tab label */
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    border: 1px solid #2F80ED;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
}

/* Styles for the ink bar */
:host ::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that using (in styles.scss - because I'm overriding it globally)
`.mat-ink-bar { display: none !important;}` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Since Angular (Material) 15 mat-ink-bar has been renamed. I was able to remove it with the following snippet in global scss:

```
.mdc-tab-indicator__content {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same issue, I have fixed like this

```
/* header */
::ng-deep.mat-tab-group .mat-tab-header, .mat-tab-nav-bar .mat-tab-header{
  border-bottom: none;
}

/* ink bar style */
::ng-deep.mat-tab-group .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar .mat-ink-bar{
 display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* header */
::ng-deep.mat-tab-group .mat-tab-header, .mat-tab-nav-bar .mat-tab-header{
  border-bottom: none;
}

/* ink bar style */
::ng-deep.mat-tab-group .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar .mat-ink-bar{
 display: none !important;
}
```